# Lights don't emit anymore

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I followed along with a tutorial to texture the earth in cycles. Everything worked well and looked nice until I changed the sample rate. The planes I used for lighting turned black and my renders are without lights.

I tried to add a normal light, no better results. Is there a setting that I could have enabled that could be the cause of this?

Here you can see a screenshot of the rendered view with the light emitting plane.

[image]

Comment: did you change any of the values for clamp direct or indirect?

Comment: Not that I know, clamp direct is set to 0.03 I assume that it should be 0?

Comment: It works again! Thank you so much :)
Could you explain what clamp does? And eventually set your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?